# Jogger mode on iOS 9.0.2 - Disable track shuffling when shaking the iPhone

Tags: music.app

There must be somewhere a "Jogger mode" option. When enabling the "Jogger mode", shaking the iPhone won't result in shuffling the playlist. (It is pretty practical during jogging, since you won't keep on shuffling your playlist during running.)

Could you please help me, where could I find this option? I would like to enable it, but I can't find it in the settings on my iPhone 5c (ME501DN/A) with iOS 9.0.2.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Shake to Shuffle has been gone since iOS 8.4. If it's still enabled, there is no switch to turn it off any more.

Comment: Is it possible to have it enabled or disabled on iOS 9.0.2? If "Shake to Shuffle" is gone since iOS 8.4, the jogger mode, so this feature should be disabled always for iPhones with the newer iOS versions, right?

Comment: i would imagine that removing the option would also toggle the off switch - but it's not something I ever used so I have no device it might still possibly be enabled on to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mentioned "Shake to Shuffle" feature is gone since iOS 8.4, so enabling or disabling it doesn't make sense anymore - so the option for this is also gone from the Music options screen. (Thank you Tetsujin for the tipp.)

On iOS 8.1 one can find it in options under the Music category. It is right the first option in the Music options category. You can enable or disable it here. (In English it is called "Shake to Shuffle", but I am using the iPhone in German, so is called "Schüttelfunktion" here (= "Shaking function").)